# Golang: .Scan() ignoring type template.HTML

Tags: go

So right now .Scan() is not taking in the type template.HTML; it completely ignores it and outputs nothing to the HTML. This is the one thing I am stuck on and uncertain about.

If I pass it as a string it works, but the HTML outputs as escaped characters

```
&lt;h2&gt;metus congue
```

If there is an alternative solution that would be neat.

The code is a one pager- full page here: http://pastebin.com/E4jXiv6p

The Struct

```
type Pages struct {
    Name        string
    Url         string
    Title       string
    Description string
    H1          string
    Hero        string
    Contents    template.HTML
    Sidebar     string
    Page_list   [][]string
}
```

Querying pages

```
func db_query_pages(db *sql.DB, err error, page_list [][]string) {

    var name, url, title, description, h1, hero, sidebar string

    var contents template.HTML

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM pages")

    for rows.Next() {

        rows.Scan(&name, &url, &title, &description, &h1, &hero, &contents, &sidebar)

        page := &Pages{

            Name:        name,
            Url:         url,
            Title:       title,
            Description: description,
            H1:          h1,
            Hero:        hero,
            Contents:    contents,
            Sidebar:     sidebar,
            Page_list:   page_list,
        }

        render_page(page)

    }

}
```

Rendering pages

```
func render_page(new_page *Pages) {

    http.HandleFunc(new_page.Url,
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

            templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main", new_page)

        })

}
```

HTML

```
{{define "content"}}

    <h1>{{.H1}}</h1>

    <img class="margin-bottom-md block common-border padding-md" src="{{.Hero}}">

    {{.Contents}}

{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't Marshal or Unamrshal an `html.Template`.

You either need to store the a reference to the template name, the raw template data, or the rendered html in the DB.

Comment: My solution was:

  page := &Pages{
   Contents:    template.HTML(contents),
  }